# partial match a dataframe column to pick rows of interest

Tags: r

Say,

I create a dataframe as:

```
dataframe <- data.frame("x" = c("aaa/bbb", "ccc", "ddd/eee/fff"),
                 "y" = c(9,2,1),
                 "z" = c(7,5,8))
```

and another dataframe as

```
list <- data.frame("m" = c("ccc"))
```

then I can select the matches rows from first dataframe as:

```
result<-merge(list,dataframe,by.x= "m",by.y="x")
```

but how can I match when my list dataframe is:

```
list <- data.frame("m" = c("fff","bbb"))
```

I am looking for a results like:

```
    x           y   z
aaa/bbb         9   7
ddd/eee/fff     1   8
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a merge issue but a filter one. You can try this:

```
df1[grep(paste(df2$m, collapse = "|"), df1$x), ]

#             x y z
# 1     aaa/bbb 9 7
# 3 ddd/eee/fff 1 8
```

It's not a good habit to assign variables with existing object or function names. So I change your `dataframe` and `list` to `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.